# Node js - Bcrypt - compare method returns false for the correct input password

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, bcrypt

I've been through various similar questions here and i tried them all, but still, the result is always "wrong password".

I'm using bcrypt for nodejs and my password hashes are stored in an Postgresql database.

The `hash` and `compare` methods are as follow :

```
generateHash : function(password, callBack){

    bcrypt.genSalt(8, function(err, salt) {

        bcrypt.hash(password, salt, callBack);
    });
}

validPassword : function(password, callBack){

    bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, callBack);
}
```

I'm using these function in the following piece of code :

```
//Generating hashing and DB storing
User.generateHash(password, function(err, hash) {

    // if there is no user with that email
    // create the user
    var newUser = User.build({

        email: email,
        password: hash
        })
        .save()
        .then(function(newUser) {

            return done(null, newUser);
        })
        .catch(function(err){

            return done(err, false);
        });
   });

//...
//Checking the password input for login

user.validPassword(password, function(err, res) {

     if(err) throw err;

     if(!res){

         return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); 
     }
     else{

         // all is well, return successful user
         return done(null, user);
     }
});
```

I hope that was clear. Thanks in advance. Ciao.

**Update I :** `callBack` added to `validPassword`, although this didn't fix the problem. And i have also checked the `this.password` value, it's correct and as expected. So, the problem is still present.

Comment: Could you post an example `this.password` value so I can see if it's indeed a valid bcrypt hash? Also, which bcrypt module are you using? And it could be of use to add where the `validPassword` and `generateHash` functions are defined. (as it seems they're properties of an object because of the way you're defining them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just solved the problem. lol it was a series of errors that made this hard to figure it out. So i'm just going to enumerate what must be done to avoid such things :

1. The `hash` must be stored in the database as a `varchar` and not as a `char`. The latest cause the hash to be of a non correct length, and so the comparison will fail. `varchar` is the solution to this.
2. Handling the comparison result must be done inside of the callBack function. This is due to nodejs being asynchronous. This was correct (see code in the question) i just want to point it out. Otherwise, the result of the comparison would be `undefined`.

I hope this will help some of you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to add `callBack` as parameter to

`validPassword : function(password){`

Try if adding that solves your problem, so change it to

`validPassword : function(password, callBack){`

Also, I don't know where your `validPassword` function is in, but you might want to check if `this.password` does indeed refer to the users password.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the callBack and also checked the value of this.password, the latest is correct and the callBack did fix the prob...any thoughts?

Comment: Hi again @leroydev , this.password contains a hash, but the question is, is it the correct hash that was stored in the DB? how can i know?

Comment: @PicoYou if it's a hash it'll most likely be the correct hash. You could open up pgAdmin or something similar and check if `this.password` matches the `password` column for the particular user in the database.

Comment: Oh...sorry for the first comment, i said "the callBack fixed the prob" lol, i was going to say "didn't", i just re-read it...so sorry for the mistake @leroydev

Comment: @PicoYou no problem I understood it. So could you please give some more context and information? (the things I asked about in the comment on your question)

Comment: Thanks @leroydev, I have some news : i used https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator to test out the bcrypt algorithm for the hash stored on my DB and the plain text password, the hash is correct and so there is a match. I printed the `this.password` value and it is correct. So i think the prob is in the `bcrypt.compare` function...what do you think?

Comment: @PicoYou what npm package do you use for bcrypt?

Comment: i'm using `bcrypt`... (`var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt');`)

Comment: Hey, i just solved the problem, it was caused by the `callBack` passed to `validPassword` function so i did handle the result of the comparison right there and not after calling it with `user.validPassword`. See answer for details
Thanks for your time @leroydev